# List a deleted tag synonym creator's ID number instead of "anon"

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-accounts, tag-synonyms

Over at the  [Meta SE tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?page=3&tab=newest&dir=descending&filter=active) page, I saw the synonym "tag-merge --> retag-request":

[image: k]

which was created by a deleted user - if their account wasn't deleted, it would have provided a hyperlink to their profile.  But instead of showing their user ID under the "Creator" list, which is normally shown in place of their username for a deleted account, it just shows "anon".  Why is this?

My request:  Can we show the user's ID number in place of "anon" under the "Creator" list, as is done everywhere else for a deleted account?